# R documentation with Roxygen?

Tags: documentation, r, roxygen

I find R documentation to be important but also time-consuming to create/maintain.  Has anyone used [**Roxygen**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen) yet, and if so, does it help in maintaining an R package?  I've used Doxygen in the past, but those projects didn't have the *man* structure that R packages require.

You can find [the vignette here](http://roxygen.org/roxygen.pdf).

Comment: I have followed Roxygen since the Summer of Code 2008 where it was put together but haven't switched to using it yet either,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, I use it all the time (in five packages and counting).  It's fantastic!  With it I managed to create a complete R package (stringr) in about five hours.

I recently submitted a patch to get a 10-fold speed up, which makes it even nicer to use.

Comment: Thanks Hadley!  I'm convinced.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to start using it, but as far as I know it doesn't yet support S4 classes, which I use extensively.

Comment: As of 3.0.0., this is no longer true. Roxygen2 completely supports S4, and has budding support for RC.