# What are good example R packages written using RUnit or roxygen?

Tags: r, roxygen

I'm writing an [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) package that's going to be used by others, so I'm trying to get this one right!  I want to use [roxygen](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen/index.html) for documentation and [RUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RUnit/index.html) for unit testing, but I haven't used them before.

What packages exist (either on CRAN or elsewhere) that use either of these tools well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [RUnit page at CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RUnit) you see the list of of packages that have a Depends:, Imports: or Suggests: on it. Maybe try one of those?  The list includes [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr) and a bunch of Rmetrics packages.

Likewise, the [roxygen page at CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/package=roxygen) can be looked at but it only lists a single package.

Comment: Ideally a package doesn't end up with a dependency on roxygen when its used.

Comment: Absolutely! That's generally the best way to find packages that use another package.

Answer (score 7):

Roxygen is used in Hadley's [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) (see also this previous SO question: [R documentation with Roxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734470/r-documentation-with-roxygen)), [mutatr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mutatr/index.html) and [testthat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html) packages.

But [testthat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html) is used for testing in the mentioned packages instead of RUnit.