# R: when to use setGeneric or export a s4 method in the namespace

Tags: r, oop, r-s4, bioconductor

I am writing a small R package with the idea to submit it to Bioconductor in the future, which is why I decided to try out s4 classes. Unfortunately I had problems understanding when I should use setGeneric or not in my package, and the documentation for the `setGeneric` method is for me more or less incomprehensible.

Concrete example:

1. I created a s4 class called *Foo*
2. I defined a method for the `[<-` operator using `setMethod("[","Foo", ...)`
3. I defined a method for the `as.list` function using `setMethod("as.list", "Foo",...)`
4. I avoided using `setGenerics` and exporting my methods in the namespace as I read somewhere that it's not needed for already defined generic functions

The problem now is that the `[` accessor method works like a charm, but `as.list` is not working. Even more confusing, when I import the library **BiocGenerics** by typing `library(BiocGenerics)` at the R terminal, `as.list` starts to work.

Question 1: how can I be sure that `[` will always work? And it is not just a coincidence because I imported some libraries?

Question 2: what should I do to make `as.list` work? Export the method in the namespace? use `setGeneric`?

Question 3: I thought that `as.list` started to work because `setGeneric("as.list"...)` was used in the BiocGenerics package, but this does not seem to be the case, reading from here: http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/BiocGenerics/man/BiocGenerics.pdf
So why did `as.list` start to work? Where was it defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an R session with only the base packages and methods loaded you can see that the generic for "[" is defined, and the generic for "as.list" is not

```
> getGeneric("[")
standardGeneric for "[" defined from package "base"

function (x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) 
standardGeneric("[", .Primitive("["))
<bytecode: 0x28f7990>
<environment: 0x28ebef0>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, i, j, drop
Use  showMethods("[")  for currently available ones.
> getGeneric("as.list")
NULL
```

Loading BiocGenerics does define the generic for as.list

```
> suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(BiocGenerics))
> getGeneric("as.list")
standardGeneric for "as.list" defined from package "base"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("as.list")
<environment: 0x5969210>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("as.list")  for currently available ones.
```

If your package is destined for use in Bioconductor, then re-use the generic from BiocGenerics. Do this with the following in your NAMESPACE file

```
import(methods)
import(BiocGenerics)

exportMethods("[", "as.list")
```

and with the following in your DESCRIPTION file

```
Imports: methods, BiocGenerics
```

If you do not import the generic from BiocGenerics, then your `setMethod("as.list", ...)` will create it's own generic. In the context of Bioconductor, a user would have to say `YourPkg::as.list(YourObject)` or `BiocGenerics::as.list(NotYourObject)` which is clearly not a good idea.

You need to `import(methods)` because in your interactive trials you're relying on the methods package to be on the search() path. But (a) R CMD BATCH runs without the methods package attached and (b) it is best practice to rely on symbols that are explicitly *in* your name space, rather than merely on the search path (and hence subject to masking by other packages or user functions with arbitrary behavior. This applies as much to the methods package as any other.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if "as.list" works just by using "setMethods" and exporting it, why should I import "BiocGenerics"? and why should I import "methods"?

Comment: Probably want: `Depends: BiocGenerics` in the `DESCRIPTION` file, so that the user sees the generics.

Comment: It took me some more steps to make it actually work, which I have shared as an answer to another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137912/rd-file-name-conflict-when-extending-a-s4-method-of-some-other-package/34452635#34452635