# S4 class cross-references - what is appropriate syntax?

Tags: r, devtools, r-s4, cran, roxygen2

I'm writing an R package and currently running `R CMD check` via `devtools::check()`

I have the following `roxygen2` in **two** of my functions that reference an S4 class (both functions return objects of this class):

```
#' @return An object of class \code{\link{mod_imputeMulti}}
#' @aliases mod_imputeMulti
#' @seealso \code{\link{multinomial_em}}, \code{\link{multinomial_impute}}
```

Yet I get the following WARNING:

> Rd files with duplicated alias 'mod_imputeMulti': 
>     'multinomial_data_aug.Rd' 'multinomial_em.Rd'

If I don't use second line -- the `@aliases` tag, I get this WARNING, despite the fact that I **do** have a link:

> checking Rd cross-references ... WARNING 
>   Missing link or links in documentation object 'multinomial_data_aug.Rd':
>     'mod_imputeMulti'
>
> Missing link or links in documentation object 'multinomial_em.Rd':
>     'mod_imputeMulti'
>
> See section 'Cross-references' in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.

*Note: adding `\code{\link{mod_imputeMulti}}` to `@seealso` doesn't change this (second) WARNING*

**What is the correct syntax?**

I've looked at a lot of references but can't find the solution anywhere:

- [Hadley's book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-classes)
- [The R extensions manual-cross references](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Cross_002dreferences)
- [The roxygen2 manual](http://roxygen.org/roxygen2-manual.pdf)
- [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356120)

I hope this is an easy one for someone--thanks in advance for the help!

#### Edit:

The S4 class documenation is provided below:

```
#' Class "mod_imputeMulti"
#'  
#' @name mod_imputeMulti-class
#' @description A multivariate multinomial model imputed by EM or Data Augmentation is 
#' represented as a \code{\linkS4class{mod_imputeMulti}} object. A complete 
#' dataset and model is represented as an \code{\linkS4class{imputeMulti}} object.
#' Slots for \code{mod_imputeMulti} objects include: (1) the modeling method; 
#' (2) the call to the estimation function; (3) the number of iterations in estimation;
#' (4) the final log-likelihood; (5) the conjugate prior if any; (6) the MLE estimate of
#' the sufficient statistics and parameters.
#' @docType class
#' @section Objects from the class: Objects are created by calls to
#' \code{\link{multinomial_impute}}, \code{\link{multinomial_em}}, or
#' \code{\link{multinomial_data_aug}}.
#' @seealso \code{\link{multinomial_impute}}, \code{\link{multinomial_em}}, 
#' \code{\link{multinomial_data_aug}}
#' @export
setClass("mod_imputeMulti",
         representation= list(
           method= "character",
           mle_call= "call",
           mle_iter= "numeric",
           mle_log_lik= "numeric",
           mle_cp= "character",
           mle_x_y= "data.frame"),
         validity= function(object) {
           if (!object@method %in% c("EM", "DA", "NULL")) {
             return("Currently only EM and DA methods are defined.")
           } else if (object@mle_iter < 0) {
             return("A negative iteration was given.")
           }
           return(TRUE)
         }
)
```

Comment: @Thomas I only used aliases because of another error I was getting without it. I've updated the post to give a more complete description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, this was a relatively simple fix.**

As you can see in the S4 class documenation at the bottom of the OP, note that the name is `mod_imputeMulti-class`, not `mod_imputeMulti`.

I needed to add **"-class"**. The `@aliases` tag is unneeded.

```
#' @return An object of class \code{\link{mod_imputeMulti-class}}
```

Also, thanks to @thomas for pointing out the use of `@slot` for proper translation of the `roxygen2` tagging to `man/*.Md` files.