# How to properly document two S4 methods for the same generic with a single help page using Roxygen2?

Tags: r, r-package, r-s4, roxygen2, roxygen

I'm building an R package using Roxygen2 for documentation. I want to implement the same S4 method for each of two classes my program has. I don't know how to properly set up the documentation for them in order to get a single help page.

I've spent the day trying to find the good configuration for it and I've checked multiple posts (e.g., [a](https://roxygen-devel.r-forge.r-project.narkive.com/SIkvgi29/documenting-multiple-methods-for-a-generic-s4-method), [b](https://gist.github.com/jefferys/b79fe87314b0dc72fec9), [c](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-document-s4-methods-for-an-existing-generic/28623/6)), but I'm still unable to get it to work properly.

My two classes look like this:

```
#' @title Class: Class1
#' @description Description for Class1.
#' @slot x an x.
#' @rdname Class1-class
#' @export
setClass("Class1", representation(x = "numeric"))
```

```
#' @title Class: Class2
#' @description Description for Class 2.
#' @slot y a y.
#' @slot z a z.
#' @rdname Class2-class
#' @export
setClass("Class2", representation(y = "numeric", z = "numeric"))
```

For both classes I want to implement `myMethod`. Thus, following the suggestion of [this article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html) I've created a dummy documentation file where I document NULL and I set up an informative @name.

The dummy documentation file looks like this:

```
#' @title myMethod
#' @description Runs myMethod.
#' @param object an object.
#' @name myMethod
NULL
```

**Attempt 1**

The implementation of the methods looks like this:

For Class1

```
if(!isGeneric("myMethod")) {setGeneric("myMethod", function(object) standardGeneric("myMethod"))}

#' @rdname myMethod
#' @export
setMethod("myMethod", "Class1", function(object) myMethod.Class1(object))

myMethod.Class1 <- function(object) return(5+object@x)
```

For Class2

```
if(!isGeneric("myMethod")) {setGeneric("myMethod", function(object) standardGeneric("myMethod"))}

#' @rdname myMethod
#' @export
setMethod("myMethod", "Class2", function(object) myMethod.Class2(object))

myMethod.Class2 <- function(object) return(object@y+object@z)
```

I can check my package and get no errors, warnings or notes. However, I want a single help page for `myMethod` and the structure above is giving me two help pages: `myMethod` and `myMethod-method`. Note that in the single help page I want, I expect also to have a single general description, the one that I've wrote in my dummy file, and not two merged descriptions.

I don't know how should I set up the documentation so that I obtain a single `myMethod` help page.

**Attempt 2**

In addition to the setup above, I've tried the structure proposed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423698) as follows:

For Class1

```
if(!isGeneric("myMethod")) {setGeneric("myMethod", function(object) standardGeneric("myMethod"))}

#' @rdname myMethod-methods
#' @aliases myMethod,Class1,Class1-method
setMethod("myMethod", "Class1", function(object) myMethod.Class1(object))

myMethod.Class1 <- function(object) return(5+object@x)
```

For Class2

```
if(!isGeneric("myMethod")) {setGeneric("myMethod", function(object) standardGeneric("myMethod"))}

#' @rdname myMethod-methods
#' @aliases myMethod,Class2,Class2-method
setMethod("myMethod", "Class2", function(object) myMethod.Class2(object))

myMethod.Class2 <- function(object) return(object@y+object@z)
```

With this structure I get a single help page named `myMethod` as I want. However, I also get a *"myMethod-methods.Rd is missing name/title. Skipping"* error during Install and Restart. No problems when checking. I don't know if this structure is the way to go but there is something missing in order to remove the error.

Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

In a file named `aaa.r` (or, basically, with a filename that comes before any other file in your `/R` folder in the package), put:

`setGeneric("myMethod", function(object) standardGeneric("myMethod"))`

Then, create one file for each class, `class1.r` and `class2.r` (you could also put them in the same file). They contain:

```
#' @title Class: Class1
#' @description Description for Class1.
#' @slot x an x.
#' @rdname Class1-class
#' @export
setClass("Class1", representation(x = "numeric"))
```

and

```
#' @title Class: Class2
#' @description Description for Class 2.
#' @slot y a y.
#' @slot z a z.
#' @rdname Class2-class
#' @export
setClass("Class2", representation(y = "numeric", z = "numeric"))
```

Finally, in a file named `myMethod.r`, put your methods definitions:

```
#' @title myMethod
#' @description Runs myMethod.
#' @param object an object.
#' @rdname myMethod
#' @exportMethod myMethod
setMethod("myMethod", "Class1", function(object) myMethod.Class1(object))
myMethod.Class1 <- function(object) return(5+object@x)

#' @rdname myMethod
#' @exportMethod myMethod
setMethod("myMethod", "Class2", function(object) myMethod.Class2(object))
myMethod.Class2 <- function(object) return(object@y+object@z)
```

I think your issue was writing the documentation for your method, then ending in a `NULL` line, which is usually used for documentation objects that don't pertain to functions/methods (e.g., a data object that comes with the package, or a tutorial).